# vim: Execute command for FileGroup

Tags: vim

I try to open NERDtree whenever I open a Golang file:

```
au FileType go exe 'NERDTree'
```

However, when I open a Go file from another directory it still displays the current directory. I can pass the directory as an argument but I do not know how to get the directory of the file to be opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current filename is accessible through the special `%` name ([`:help cmdline-special`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special)); you can modify that into a full path and then cut off the file name itself to obtain the path: `%:p:h`, cp. [`:help filename-modifiers`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers).

That could be directly passed to built-in commands like `:edit`, unfortunately not to `:NERDTree`. For that, we have to explicitly `expand()` it, and then interpolate the result into the command-line via `:execute` (which in your question would not be necessary to use):

```
autocmd FileType go execute 'NERDTree' expand('%:p:h')
```

Alternatively, you could also just `:set autochdir`, so Vim will switch directories automatically.

#### autocmd FileType doesn't scale well

I would recommend putting any settings, mappings, and filetype-specific autocmds into `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}_whatever.vim` (or `{filetype}/whatever.vim`; cp. `:help ftplugin-name`) instead of defining lots of `:autocmd FileType {filetype}`; it's cleaner and scales better; requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`, though. Settings that *override* stuff in default filetype plugins should go into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` instead.